# unable to loop over nested array in JSON in Excel VBA using JsonConverter.bas from Github

Tags: arrays, json, vba, nested

My JSON file looks like this:

```
    {
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "6003510075864",
         "name": "Golf",
         "audience_size": 242637550,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Sports and outdoors",
            "Sports",
            "Golf"
         ],
         "description": "",
         "topic": "Sports and outdoors"
      },
      {
         "id": "6003393973731",
         "name": "Persian Gulf",
         "audience_size": 173453990,
         "path": [
            "Interests",
            "Additional Interests",
            "Persian Gulf"
         ],
         "description": null,
         "topic": "Hobbies and activities"
      },...
```

As you can see, there is a nested array "path" , with an unknown length.

With this code im trying to access the section:

```
 Dim hReq As Object, JSON As Object, item As Object, itempath As Object
(...)
    For Each item In JSON("data")
        ws.Cells(3 + i, 1) = item("id")
        ws.Cells(3 + i, 2) = item("name")
        ws.Cells(3 + i, 3) = item("audience_size")
        ws.Cells(3 + i, 4) = item("description")
        ws.Cells(3 + i, 5) = item("topic")

        For Each itempath In item("path") ' <<< in this line I get the error Object needed.. 
            ws.Cells(3 + i, 6) = itempath("0")
        Next          
        i = i + 1    
    Next
```

The 2nd For each statement gives me an error .. I dont know how to handle this nested array ... thanks for any ideas ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
item("path")
```

...is a Collection of strings, not a collection of objects

```
Dim itempath 'as variant

'...
For Each itempath In item("path") 
    ws.Cells(3 + i, 6) = itempath
Next 
'...
```

Comment: Ok that works thanks tim... But I had to use variant... anyway.. ;)